# BotBuilder repo moved?

Tags: botframework

I used to see cSharp and nodejs core, examples under this location https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder which I don't see from today. 
Has anything changed ? Repo moved or merged ?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation displayed on the page you indicated:

[image: Repo moved]

This is linking to https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-v3 which is hosting the v3 now

Answer (score 0):

The V3 SDK is now available from https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-v3